# Haskell - determine set of free and bounded variables of a function

Tags: variables, haskell, let, free-variable

I have to determine the set of free and bounded variables of the function s1 and s2:

```
s1 := \x -> if y then \z -> (x \y -> y) else (\z -> w) x
```

So, for s1 I'll write:

```
FV(s1):= FV (y) ∪ FV (x) ∪ FV (w)
```

Am I correct? Or should it be:

```
FV(s1):= FV (y) ∪ FV (x) ∪ FV (y) ∪ FV (w) ∪ FV (x)
```

since y and x are two times free.
Once y in If and then result of -> y
and for x: x is free once in the result of \z and second at the end.

The bounded variables would be:

```
BV(s1):= BV (x) ∪ BV (z) ∪ BV (y) ∪ BV (z)
```

since z occurs twice as bounded var.

In the same way I'd determine the FVs and BVs of s2:

```
s2 := let f x1  x2 = y1  (\x -> x2) in let y1 = f w (f y2  y2), y2 = y1  in f

FV(s2):= FV (y1) ∪ FV (x2) ∪ FV (w) ∪ FV (y1)

BV(s2):= BV (f) ∪ BV (x1) ∪ BV (x2) ∪ BV (x) ∪ BV (y1)
```

Could you please tell me whether I'm correct or wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `s1`, is `(x \y -> y)` supposed to be `x (\y -> y)`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this `(x \y -> y)` is written in my exercise sheet..

Comment: GHC cannot parse it--it would have to be either `(\x y -> y)` or `x (\y -> y)`; I would lean toward the former.

In any event, stackoverflow is not here to check your homework; is there a specific question you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

### General idea: bound vs free variables

A rule of thumb for free and bound variables is that the value of a free variable affects the value of the expression.

For a simple example, if I defined `identity x = x` and separately said `x = 6`, it wouldn't change the fact that `identity 10` is `10`; in `identity x = x`, the variable `x` is bound because it just stands for whatever input there is. We can write `identity y = y` without changing the meaning of the function.

Conversely, if we define `gimmez x = z`, `z` isn't bound. If we separately say `z = 6` then `gimmez` does something very different to if we said `z = putStrLn "zed zed zed zed can you tell I'm British?"`, or `gimmez x = zz`. In either case, the function `gimmez` has changed - the `z` wasn't bound.

Can I do find-and-replace `varname` for `othervarname` without changing the meaning?

- Yes - `varname` is bound.
- No - `varname` appears free in the expression.

---

Let's look at your actual examples

### Example 1

```
s1 := \x -> if y then \z -> (x \y -> y) else (\z -> w)
```

You wrote `FV(s1):= FV (y) ∪ FV (x) ∪ FV (w)` or `FV(s1):= FV (y) ∪ FV (x) ∪ FV (y) ∪ FV (w) ∪ FV (x)`

Let's look at all the variables in turn

- The initial `\x ->` binds `x` for the scope of the lambda - to the end of the line. It's not a free variable at all.
- `y` is free after the `if`, but bound in the invalid expression `(x \y -> y)`. The second occurrence in that bracket has the value of the bound y, rather than the free one. This obliteration of an otherwise free variable is called shadowing. `y` is free in the expression, but only because of its first appearance.
- `z` is bound in the final lambda expression.
- `w` isn't bound anywhere - it's free.

**Summary:** `y` and `z` are free. `x` and `z` are bound, `y` is shadowed - it also occurs as a bound variable later in the expression. `FV(s1) = {y,z}`, and `BV(s1)={x,z,y}`

### Notation

I disagree with the use of the notation  `FV(s1):= FV (y) ∪ FV (w)`. This suggests that to find the free variables of `s1` I should look at the free variables of `y` and `w`. I disagree - `y` and `z` **are** the free variables of `s1`. It is true that if I wanted to get the free variables of the module in which `s1` is defined I would need to add  `FV (y) ∪ FV (w)`, but that's a different question.

(The notation `∪` indicates set union. Things are either in or out of a set, you don't need to add them multiple times.)

### Example 2

```
s2 := let f x1  x2 = y1  (\x -> x2) in let y1 = f w (f y2  y2), y2 = y1  in f
```

The `let f x1 x2 =` binds `f`, `x1` and `x2`, even if `f` feels different; they all introduce a new variable which would shadow any external definition with the same name, and find-and-replacing them in the expression wouldn't change its meaning, so they're bound.

- `f`, `x1`, `x2` are bound by the `let`.
- `y1` is free the first time it appears - the second `let` binding is not in scope here.
- `x` is bound by a lambda
- `y1` is bound by a `let` now (more shadowing)
- `w` is free
- `y2` looks free at first, but is actually retrospectively bound in the expression `y2 = y1`

```
FV(s2):= {y1, w}
BV(s2):= {f, x1, x2, x, y1, y2}
```